# Submit payload data as a non json format with Ext.ajax.Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs5

I want to submit data using `Ext.ajax.Request`, but the payload being sent is in json format:

```
{name: 'john gold', id:1, company:'abcde'}
```

but, i want to submit the payload in simple format:

```
name=john+gold&id=1&company=abcde
```

how can i achieve this ?

my method looks like:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    params: payload,  

    success: function(response) {
        var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText).data;
        console.log("search data : *** \n" + data);

        this.fireEvent("aftersubmit", params, data);
    },
    scope: this
});
```

Comment: which technology at serverside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `method: 'GET'` if you want the params in the url.

**Update**

You'll got to convert the payload yourself then... [`Ext.Ajax#request`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-method-request) accepts a string as its params option, and you "url encode" your data object with [`Ext.Object.toQueryString`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-toQueryString). So something like that:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    // ...
    method: 'POST',
    params: Ext.Object.toQueryString(payload)
});
```

Comment: I want the params in the body since its post, put request.
Its only the format of the payload that im unable to change.

Comment: Using any rest client (eg: chrome plugin), if i submit a put or a post request, the payload is sent in a non json structure.
How can i achieve this with Ext.ajax.Request, with store/model object containing the data